# How to use parallel port to work like switch which read(get) signals and in java listening to that which is true or not?

Tags: java, rxtx, parallel-port

Hi 
i want to use lpt port for interfacing the switch (for example ,signal the 5v to some pin)  listening to some pin and notify my app ?
i use rxtx-2.1-7-bins-r2 in windows.
i used the isPrinterBusy() and isPrinterError() methods and signal the 5v to corresponding pins, but i get true at all ! :|
regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is solved, with some hardware things,i tied the parallel port status lines 10 and 11 to Ground and lines 12, 13 and 15 5V, after that used the same methods( isPrinterBusy() and isPrinterError()) and got false when i switched the 5v to that pins!
for more information about pins[25 Pin LPT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:25_Pin_D-sub_pinout.svg)